# SAS Regex to match 1-3 digits

Tags: regex, sas

I am looking for a SAS regex to match 1-3 digits at the beginning of a string, and such digit sequence should be followed by whitespace - as shown below (`string1`, `string2` and `string3`):

```
data _null_;
string1='1   y';
string2='22  x';
string3='333 z';
string4='z1   y';
string5='2z  x';
rx=prxparse('/^\d????/');
if prxmatch(rx,string1) then put 'match';
if prxmatch(rx,string2) then put 'match';
if prxmatch(rx,string3) then put 'match';
if prxmatch(rx,string4) then put 'notmatch';
if prxmatch(rx,string5) then put 'notmatch';
run;
```

Comment: How is this "not a real question" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just for fun, a few trivial non-regex solutions (each have weaknesses/strengths depending on your data/desired results)...  I don't check for length here with most of these so if you need to eliminate situations where you have 4 or more digits (ie, if string1="1234 main" would fail) add that via length().

```
if notdigit(scan(string1,1)) then put 'no match';
if compress(scan(string,1),,'d') ne ' ' then put 'no match';
```

NOTDIGIT is a great function for something like this - if you don't need to check for 4+ characters this is probably a much faster solution than the regex.

Also, a suggestion - for SAS, if you're on 9.2 or newer, you should write your regex this way:

```
rx=prxparse('/^\d{1,3}(?=\s)/o');
```

o indicates to the compiler to only compile the regex once.  (This replaces the old 'retain and if `_n_`=1' method.)  You also might want to use \b instead of \s  if you want to match 3 digits and nothing else (ie, if "333" is a match, as opposed to "333 ", and it's possible to have a 3 width variable) - \s is a whitespace character, while \b is a word boundary, which is similar to \s but includes the end of string marker as well.

Answer (score 1):

It is a little bit unclear what you are looking for, but I believe you need this regex pattern

```
^\d{1,3}(?=\s)
```

Comment: Can you please explain what this regex does?  I get the d{1,3} part (match 1-3 digits), how does the second bit work?

Comment: @RawFocus : Positive lookahead `(?=\s)` ensure space is behind the match (zero-width assertions)

Comment: @RawFocus - I highly suggest www.regular-expressions.info as a regex guide - it's a well presented, information packed resource that covers nearly everything imaginable.

Comment: Additionally, use the SAS regex tip sheet to convert what you learn on the above site into SAS.  The syntax can differ: http://support.sas.com/rnd/base/datastep/perl_regexp/regexp-tip-sheet.pdf